# WCF Sync with out a primary identity column

Tags: sql, wcf, windows-mobile, synchronization

I am doing an application in which I have some Windows Mobile devices which will synchronize with main database (Server) once a day using WCF Sync. For most of the tables in the client, the data is coming from the server, and later on only updates on those rows will be synchronized with the server.

Now the problem I'm facing is that I have a table in which data will be added throughout the day on each client database. But with those new rows on each client databases I have not been able to synchronize, because the primary key identity fields are going to be same on each client table. When they are synchronizing it will be fine for the first client, but what about the second device? Can anyone please help me to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only true if your Identities are sequential integers.

If you make your ID field a GUID, then you won't have this problem.